# How to create a 2D array of unknown length in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

So I need to store data that looks like this:

```
map[x,y] = z;
map[1,3] = 5;
map[2,6] = 8;
```

The problem is x and y are of unknown length. I'm assuming I need something like a List or Dictionary but I'm not exactly sure which one or how to implement it (add and get values from it).

Comment: They hide that information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unknown length forever, or only when you start? Do you expect this to be densely populated? How big will it be? Fundamentally you *could* use a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>` but that may be rather inefficient.

Comment: Already been answered-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723290/how-can-i-create-a-2-dimensional-dynamic-length-array

Comment: Is the data actually as sparse as your example? You have a 2x6 matrix with 2 values so far. If so, I'd look up C# sparse matrix and see what you get. This is especially important if x and y could be very large at runtime, you'll run out of memory with a full array implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your solution seems like what I would need. Unknown length is forever. x and y will range from 1 to about 400-600, z will range from about 1 to 50. It will be somewhat densely populated. I imagine if x and y are 500 or so, there will be about 200-300 entries (so about 50% of the possible x/y indexes will have a value). Efficiency is pretty important since values will have to get added/removed very frequently.

Comment: It should also be noted a `Dictionary` will not work in this case if you have any duplicate sets of coordinates, as 'Key' values in a dictionary must be unique (I'm assuming,  of course, that you can have duplicate X ,Y coordinate pair.)

Comment: Is there a requirement to store it in an array or a multiple dimensional list/array of a given type. or is it simply a requirement to add, find,and remove. Are there special run-time requirements of some sort. If not I would just create a managed dictionary class.

Comment: @Gary.Taylor717 There would be no duplicate sets of coordinates. Any one set of x,y can only have one z value.

Comment: To answer the actual question, have you tried just `int[,] map = new int[x,y]`?

Answer (score 3):

Declaration and initialization of the 2D list:

```
List<List<int>> list2D = new List<List<int>>();
```

Adding to the first dimension (a list of integers):

```
list2D.Add(new List<int>());
```

Adding to the second dimension of the list (index of first dimension and the integer value your'e adding):

```
list2D[0].Add(123);
```

Here is the MSDN article on the `List` object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

> public object this[int x, int y] { get; set; }

For me that's the easiest option to use in C# 6 or later, because once the class is created I don't have to initialise or create sub collections.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new Matrix();
        array[1,0] = "cat";
        array[0,1]="dog";
        Console.WriteLine(array[0, 1]);
        array[0, 1] = null;
    }
}

class Matrix
{
    private Dictionary<string,Object> Data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    public object this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            string key = this.GetKey(x, y);
            return Data.ContainsKey(key) ? Data[key] : null;
        }
        set
        {
            string key = this.GetKey(x, y);
            if(value==null)
                Data.Remove(key);
            else
                Data[key] = value;
        }
    }
    private string GetKey(int x, int y)
    {
        return String.Join(",", new[] { x, y });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly the way I wanted it to. I had to make some changes so that it returns int instead of object but thanks for the push in the right direction!